# Rails 4, Stripe: conditionally display Stripe data by Rails environment?

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, stripe-payments

Using Stripe for billing services and it works great.  However, testing is a bit of a pain.

I'm using rspec/capybara and have some feature tests that visit a `/settings` page where the user may update their email, password, and billing information (via Stripe).  In development and production, I want to display a list of invoices from the Stripe API.  However, in test mode I don't want to display the invoices as it's expensive and I don't have valid customer tokens to communicate with the Stripe API.

My solution is something likes:

```
# settings.html.erb view
<% unless Rails.env.test? %>
  <% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
    # display info for the invoice...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It just seems "wrong" to me to do a conditional on the Rails environment that way.

The issue is that if I execute the calls to Stripe's API I'd have to ensure I have valid customer/card tokens that communicate with Stripe and that's expensive and depends on a 3rd-party for my tests.

My approach at the moment is to assume that Stripe is testing their API effectively so I only really test the values I pass to Stripe's API. And anytime I display data from Stripe I skip it in test mode.

Are there any cleaner solutions to this type of problem?  It should be the same general concept with any 3rd-part API that may be used when you run tests.

Update: 2014-03-27 12:20

Another thing I'm considering is actually taking the penalty of creating valid Stripe customer/card tokens when I do some of my feature tests.  I'm torn because I see the need for a stubbed-out faster testing mechanism, yet if my tests aren't actually doing the same code they would do in production, I'm really missing out on the "working code" part.

I would probably tag my rspec tests that make Stripe API calls with a "stripe" tag and run those only when I needed to do a full check (usually before a major commit or deployment).

I guess at some point if you're really going to "test" things then you have to take the penalty and use the APIs just like your users would.

I have looked at some stubbing gems that mimic Stripe locally, but now I'm adding a 4th-party into the system.  I'd prefer not to do that as it seems to defeat the purpose of testing.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and decided to take the "penalty hit" in my tests and actually connect to Stripe's API.  I believe that's the only way to get realistic tests.  I found it usually takes about 1 second for each connection to Stripe.

I'm using [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to run my app (using Unicorn server and a Procfile) and I'm loading my Stripe API keys via ENV variables (.env file; Foreman uses [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) behind the scenes).

That means when I create test users I have to ensure they have valid stripe customer tokens.  It definitely adds a few seconds to my automated tests, but I believe the confirmation that my system works as expected is well worth a few extra seconds.

I also tagged my rspec tests with a `:stripe` tag.  Thus if I want to test everything but skip hitting Stripe's servers, I run:

`foreman run rspec --tag ~stripe [optional path]`

As a side note, if you add the following to your `spec_helper.rb` file:

`config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true`

you can skip the "true" part on your rspec tags:

`it "connects to stripe", :stripe {}` vs `it "connects to stripe", stripe: true {}`

Saves a few keystrokes and makes it easier to visually spot the tags.